# Adding JPanel to JFrame works 50% of the time

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

Below are two images showing the problem I'm facing. Whenever I run the project there is 50/50 chance that my JPanels load properly, otherwise only 1 JPanel is loaded even though I'm simply looping through array and adding JPanels to the JFrame.

```
        viewComponents.forEach(viewComponent -> this.add(viewComponent));
```

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mIjL.png)

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNDor.png)

**DashboardView.java**

```
public class DashboardView extends JFrame{
    List<ViewComponent> viewComponents = new ArrayList();
    ViewComponentFactory viewComponentFactory = new ViewComponentFactory();

    JFrame dashboardInput = new JFrame();

    public DashboardView(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        createGauges(); //Adding 2 JPanels
        viewComponents.forEach(viewComponent -> this.add(viewComponent));

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

        dashboardInput.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dashboardInput.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        createInputs(); //Adding JPanels
        dashboardInput.pack();     
        dashboardInput.setLocation(this.getX()+(this.getWidth()/2)-(dashboardInput.getWidth()/2), this.getY()+this.getHeight());
        dashboardInput.setVisible(true);

    }
private void createGauges(){
    viewComponents.add(viewComponentFactory.getViewComponent(ViewComponentFactory.ViewComponentType.RadialCircleGauge,0,800, "Speedometer", "KM/H")); 
    viewComponents.add(viewComponentFactory.getViewComponent(ViewComponentFactory.ViewComponentType.LinearGauge, -100,100, "Temperature", "Celcius"));
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DashboardView dashboardView = new DashboardView();
        dashboardView.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this LinearGauge component?  Do you have source code for it?  Does it define its preferred size properly?

Comment: Why do you have 2 JFrame? Your class extends JFrame and you attempt to add components to that frame.  Then you create another JFrame and attempt to add components to that. Don't extend JFrame and make sure the code is executed on the EDT as suggest.

Comment: This: `this.setVisible(true);` should be called **after** all components have been added to the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be, that your **DashboadView** isn't initialized within the **EDT - Thread** (Event Dispatching Thread). All GUI actions must be done within this thread. Otherwise strange things will happen (e.g. artifacts while updateing UI).

One should initialize its GUI this way, to ensure the start is wihtin the right Thread.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this with both my JFrames with no luck I make them both visible that same Thread method. I have switched the tall JPanel with the small one it seems like the issue still exists but it seems like pack(); is being called before both JPanels are painted in the JFrame for some reason.

Comment: Then there must be another problem. Are definitly both instances within viewComponents?